# convert NotesDateTime to Epoch Millisecond Format (SSJS)

Tags: datetime, xpages, epoch

I have a notesdatetime object. Now I need to convert it into epoch millisecond format, using SSJS.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `NotesDateTime` to `java.util.Date` and then you can use [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) to get the epoch.

```
ndt.toJavaDate().getTime(); //ndt is NotesDateTime object
```